# React Typescript and useCallback

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, usecallback

I'm trying to use Typescript and useCallback, but I'm having this error

`Expected 0 arguments, but got 1`

This is my code

```
const searchFriends = useCallback(() => (filterValue: string): void => {
    if (dataState.length <= INITIAL_FRIENDS_API_REQUEST) fetchAllFriends()
    const filterValueInsensitive = filterValue.toLowerCase()
    const filtered = dataState.filter((friend: Friends) => {
      return friend.displayName?.toLowerCase().includes(filterValueInsensitive)
    }) 
    setFriendsDisplayState(filtered)
  }, [dataState,fetchAllFriends]) 

  const handleChangeSearchInput = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ): void => searchFriends(e.currentTarget.value) // ERROR here "Expected 0 arguments, but got 1"
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `useCallback` syntax like `useMemo's`. It doesn't need a currying function. The correct way to write it is like

```
const searchFriends = useCallback((filterValue: string): void => {
    if (dataState.length <= INITIAL_FRIENDS_API_REQUEST) fetchAllFriends()
    const filterValueInsensitive = filterValue.toLowerCase()
    const filtered = dataState.filter((friend: Friends) => {
      return friend.displayName?.toLowerCase().includes(filterValueInsensitive)
    }) 
    setFriendsDisplayState(filtered)
  }, [dataState,fetchAllFriends])
```

Comment: Happy to have helped :-)